# C++ substring contained between 2 specific characters

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std

In c++ would like to extract all substrings in a string contained between specific characters, as example:

```
std::string str = "XPOINT:D#{MON 3};S#{1}"
std::vector<std:string> subsplit = my_needed_magic_function(str,"{}");
std::vector<int>::iterator it = subsplit.begin();
for(;it!=subsplit.end(),it++) std::cout<<*it<<endl;
```

result of this call should be:

```
MON 3
1
```

also using boost if needed.

Comment: `find` and `substr` or regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Regex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "XPOINT:D#{MON 3};S#{1}.";

    std::regex word_regex(R"(\{(.*?)\})");
    auto first = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), word_regex),
         last  = std::sregex_iterator();;

    while (first != last)
        std::cout << first++->str() << ' ';
}
```

Prints

> `{MON 3} {1}`

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/354c33843f2e9ae0).

Comment: I think that `first++->str()` is confusing... I would prefer a normal for loop.